# Scan Django App Modules

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am developing a new class to add in some functionality for my django apps and need to scan / gather each of the classes that inherit from this class. I've already got everything in place to scan for them within a particular module that I import, but I'm wondering what the best way is to scan for a specific file inside each of my apps (just the one's I've defined)? I know some other apps do things like this and obviously django itself does. I could probably hack something together to scan the file system but I was wondering if there is a better / common approach to solving this? I couldn't find much about it.

I could always just define the classes inside a single package, but since they're tied to the applications I think it would be best to define them in each app rather than importing models from all over the place.

example desired interface:

```
def get_app_implementations(module_name):
     # ... What's the least hacky way to get each of the app packages?
     # in a way that they can be imported using __import__ or the likes
     results = []
     for package in packages:
         try:
             scanned = __import__("{0}.{1}".format(package,module_name))
             results.append(scanned)
         except ImportError:
             pass
     return results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider a different approach. Rather than scanning through models to find the relevant ones, you could get the models themselves to register themselves with your system, via the use of a metaclass. [Marty Alchin](http://martyalchin.com/2008/jan/10/simple-plugin-framework/) has a great example of a simple way to do that.

Comment: This looks promising and feels much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to make django auto-import a module in each app package so that my plugins can get registered without having to explicitly call import? ;)

Comment: Sounds like the new [AppConfig functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/) in 1.7 is what you want.

Comment: AppConfig would be fine if I felt like typing an import statement for each of my 1... apps, but I remembered seeing this: `django.utils.module_loading.autodiscover` being used by the django admin, and turns out it suits what I wanted perfectly. I just make a single call `autodiscover('my_module')` inside my root app's urls.py and it automatically registers all my plugins in my_module.py for each app.

Comment: Link to gist that details my solution. Boiled everything down to a simple decorator that will auto-register implementations of the base class inside any django app without explicit imports! https://gist.github.com/RutledgePaulV/6fb72a4b700e5b3ff3fd

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the following will meet my needs, though I'm still curious if there are better solutions.

```
#loader.py
from django.conf import settings
import importlib

def load_from_apps(name):

    results = []
    for app in settings.CUSTOM_APPS:
        try:
            scanned = importlib.import_module("{0}.{1}".format(app, name))
            results.append(scanned)
        except ImportError:
            pass
    return results



#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

CUSTOM_APPS = (
    'CustomApp1',
    'CustomApp2'
)

INSTALLED_APPS += CUSTOM_APPS
```